# Shell append string to file empty line problem

Tags: file, shell

I am using this shell script to append text in a new line at the end of file, but it automatically adds a blank line at the end of the file. How to get rid of it?

```
echo -e "\n$STRING" >> "filename.txt"
```

Thanks

Comment: if you mean the file ends with a newline character, yes, that's common for text files on *nix.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`echo -ne "\n$STRING" >> "filename.txt"`

The -n means "don't add a newline".